# How do I highlight the content of a TextBox/RefEdit control and set focus simultaneously?

Tags: vba, excel, userform

I'd like to highlight the content of a TextBox/RefEdit control and set focus simultaneously when there is any invalid entry and after prompting a message box warning the error so that user knows where to fix the error. You can try `Data>Analysis>DataAnalysis>Sampling` and enter some invalid range/data, then you will be redirected to the invalid entry. The invalid entry is highlighted as well as with focus set (you can see a flickering cursor).

I tried to emulate this and I used,

```
aControl.SetFocus
aControlt.SelStart = 0
aControl.SelLength = Len(aControl.Text)
```

While the content inside the control is highlighted in blue, there's no flickering cursor as if I did not set focus of the control. How can I fix this? Or what's the best way to guide the user to the place where the invalid entry exists?

Answer (score 0):

What if user inputs more than one invalid entries. How do you plan them all selected and setfocused at the same time.

There is no need to complicate things for you and for user. What you can do is create invisible labels with the right message you want to deliver to user, preferably in red color, and place them below each TextBox/RefEdit. Make them visible with `Label1.Visible = True`within your conditional check.

Comment: My code has a validation part that checks entries in certain order, if find one invalid, then stop there. So only this invalid entry will be selected and setfocused.

Comment: May I ask the point of flicker effect after you already achieved setfocus and highlight?

Comment: For pure aesthetics, I guess. Anyway, I will probably just accept the  highlight without a flickering cursor.

Comment: You can try these if you want both cursor to flash and user to pay attention to the textbox: .SetFocus .BackColor = vbRed .Value = ""